# MSSQL Diferent execution plan for same query/data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have query that is running "fast" on production, but very slow (1hour) on test servers.

The following query is in question:

```
select z.PrimaryKeyColumn
FROM [table1] z 
inner join Table2 p on  p.PrimaryKeyColumn=z.PrimaryKeyColumn
left outer join table3 pz on z.PrimaryKeyColumn==Rtrim(rtrim(pz.column2)+LTRIM(pz.column3))
```

I analyzed query execution plan and realized that on production it uses hash match while on test it uses loop for the first join, hence the slowness. 
I have rebuilt indexes and updated statistics, but result are the same.

**Additionally, on TEST server, where results are slow, i Copied/duplicated Table2 table with indexes and data, and when i use that table then the query is fast as it is on production server...**

This are the query execution plans:

TEST server:

[image]

TEST server but using duplicate of Table2 in INNER JOIN:

[image]

PRODUCTION server:

[image]

Comment: You can use a query hint to specify the type of `JOIN`.

Comment: You have to add indexes on field used for join selections and groupings

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is the collation for p.PrimaryKeyColumn and z.PrimaryKeyColumn same?

Comment: It's ok with hash hint, but I won't to get to the bottom of this.
Indexes exists on all join selections and collation is the same.

Comment: Rebuild that table's indexes, refresh statistics. Probably test server is not being maintained on a regular manner same as prod.

Answer (score 0):

Probably both server are not the same or with different configuration. BUT something that is not necessary, remove the functions RTRIM() by comparing u will have the same result.

Comment: The funny thing is that the diference is on single server also. I made a duplicate of table1 on TEST server, so i had table1 and table1_copy, with same rows, indexes, etc. When doing query with table1 the query was slow (nested loop), when doing with table1_copy the query was fast (Hash match).I'm sory for my bad questionformulation but english is not my primary language si it's dificult to express myself.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that when you have copied table1 and table 2 to new copies has resolved the Query Plan to the same as Production does indicate that there is something different in the cardinality estimates from the original and the copy.

There has to be some differences in the statistics created for the tables, so check between them that they have the same statistics created for the original and copy.

Also review the histograms for the statistics, especially related to the different index choices observed between the plans - do the steps look the same?

Also, possible obvious and you've already confirmed - but do all the same indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: That will be the issue.  Run UPDATE STATISTICS with the same parameters on each database. Also if PROD has additional statistics created then use CREATE STATISTICS to add these to TEST.   
Although the indexes are important, the Query Engine will only use them based on the statistics present as these will provide it the knowledge that the index is beneficial by returning less data.

Comment: I already did that. I also dropped and recreated the Table2 on TEST (with slow query execution) and problem stayed the same (slow again), but with duplicate of that same table (table2) the query is fast (hash merge).